# Is a OneSignal push token the same as the app ID?

Tags: react-native, push-notification, token, onesignal, react-native-onesignal

I'm using OneSignal in my React Native app, and an endpoint in the API I'm using is asking for a OneSignal push token. The token they're asking for seems to have the same format as the `app ID` that was generated for my app on OneSignal. Are they the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

No they are not, 
The onesignal appId is the identifier for the app 
There are several types of keys in onesignal

1. The rest API key for onesignal : this can be used to call the onesignal api to send notifications (Can be found at Settings> Keys & Ids)
2. Player Id : An identifier for a specific user in your application, this can be used to send notification to a specific user in your app
3. Push token : This is something similar to Player Id and can be retrieved the same way as player id

The below code can be used to get the playerid and the pushtoken

```
componentWillMount() {
   OneSignal.init("YOUR_ONESIGNAL_APPID");
   OneSignal.addEventListener('ids', this.onIds);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    OneSignal.removeEventListener('ids', this.onIds);
}

onIds(device) {
    console.log('Device info: ', device);
}
```

The device variable will have the playerId and the pushToken

More info can be found at the [SDK Page](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/react-native-sdk)